# Create a folder with subfolder and hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select a cell in column A, run a macro to create a folder in a specific location with the cell value as the name.

Within this folder, I want two folders with specific names.

e.g.:

1. Column A cell = P18-457
2. select the cell and run the macro
3. the macro will create a folder named P18-457 in C:\Users\johndo\Desktop\Quotes (this directory will not change so every time create a folder without prompting for location)
4. within folder P18-457 create two standard folders. e.g. one called costing and the other references
5. create a hyperlink to folder P18-457 in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the sub folder you want to create within the <kbd>P18-457</kbd> folder, but the creation of the <kbd>P18-457</kbd> folder and hyperlink can be done like this.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim FolderPath As String

On Error GoTo errh:
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        'Main folder path. - This need to exist already
        FolderPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Quotes\"

        'Make the directory assuming the Quotes folder is already existing
        MkDir FolderPath & Target.value

        'Make the sub directory Costings
        MkDir FolderPath & Target.value & "\Costings"

        'Make the sub directory Reference
        MkDir FolderPath & Target.value & "\Reference"

        'Create hyperlink
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Target, Address:=FolderPath & Target.value
    End If
Exit Sub

'error handling
errh:
MsgBox "Error in creating subfolder with hyperlink" & vbCrLf & "Error no. " & Err.Number
End Sub
```

Paste that into the worksheet you are working on and it should work. To run this macro you would double click on a cell in column A

To run it Manually create a command button at copy the following code, into that command button object.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim FolderPath As String
    If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Count = 0 Then
            'Main folder path
            FolderPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Quotes\"

            'Make the directory assuming the Quotes folder is already existing
            MkDir FolderPath & ActiveCell.value

            'Make the sub directory Costings
            MkDir FolderPath & ActiveCell.value & "\Costings"

            'Make the sub directory Reference
            MkDir FolderPath & ActiveCell.value & "\Reference"

            'Create hyperlink
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:=FolderPath & ActiveCell.value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just pasted the code into the spread sheet but it is not creating the folder in the folder path I have specified.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have pasted the code into the sheet to test and created the folder path as, FolderPath = "C:\Users\" & "AU075" & "\Desktop\Test\". it doesn't seem to work, have I typed in wrong? What I mean in the subfolders is when the macro is ran to create e.g. "P18-457" folder an extra two folders will be created within "P18-457" main folder. The two extra folders will always be named the same and will always be needed in this main folder. Doing this will save the use needing to create the two extra folders in that main folder every time.

Comment: ohh, i forgot to mention, you have to double click on a cell with a value in column A, to run the macro.

Comment: ah ok, that is handy. How do I change the code and make the user run the macro manually instead of double clicking. The issue is if the user for some reason mis-types what is in the cell they will most likely double click to edit which may cause issues.

Comment: And you still only wants it to run with the selected cell, or create folders for all populated cells in column A?

Comment: Hi, only for the selected cell. The code is working just need to make it work only when we manually run the macro and not make it automatic. I have been trying to manipulate your existing code but I am struggling.

Comment: @ZoranPajkic, answer is edited to also contain a manual example

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark it as an answer to your question, so other people can see it's a valid answer :)